# Filter function with ternary

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, callback, coercion

This was bothering me for hours...and I don't understand yet why.
I have an array of of objects. Is my syntax bad for the ternary?...

This is in React if that matters.
The array is something like below

```
[{id:1, name:'steve'}, {id:2, name:'john'}]
```

if i use this, it works fine.

```
array.filter(item => { if (item.id ==id) return item.name} )
```

if I use this, it returns me the whole array, without filtering nothing.

```
array.filter(item => item.id ===id ? item.name : 'null')
```

.

Comment: The string `'null'` is truthy...

Comment: filter function traverse each entry of given array and return sub array with matched value. can you explain more what you want as output ?

Comment: ```array.filter(item => item.id ===id ? true : false)```

Comment: That works, I dont want anymore as the output, this little thing was bothering me for hours.

Comment: the anonymous function in filter should either return a true or false. returning 'null' in javascript is true. 'null' is a non empty string

Comment: @AlfredAyi-bonte No, the `filter` callback can return *anything*, the programmer just has to keep in mind that it'll be converted to a Boolean if it isn't a Boolean already

Comment: @CertainPerformance I can't agree less but that thing should evaluate to the correct boolean

Answer (score 4):

Why not just take the result of the comparison, as [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) expects a boolean value?

```
array.filter(item => item.id === id)
```

The return value of the callback does not change anything outside of `filter`, just the result of the filtering.

Answer (score 3):

`Array.filter()` works by selecting those elements from the array for which `true` value is returned. Which does not mean the boolean `true` value but any values that is defined. So, in your code you are returning `null` with quotes for the `else` part which is a string and not actually a `null` value. Thus, it considers it as a truthy and consider that object in the filtered array. Change that to `null` and it will work.

```js
var array = [{
    id: 10,
    name: "name10"
  },
  {
    id: 20,
    name: "name20"
  }
];
var id = 20;
var res = array.filter(item => item.id === id ? item.name : null);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: @born2gamble glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `filter` wrong.
You can check the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Parameters) and see that `callback` parameter is a function that returns `true` or `false`.
So in your case - you want to filter array by id and then select only name.
You can chain `filter` and `map`.

For example,

```js
let array = [{id:1, name:'steve'}, {id:2, name:'john'}];
let result = array
  .filter(item => item.id === 1)
  .map(item => item.name);

console.log(result);
```